# How do I Select characters to the left of a ',' and then characters to the right of a ','?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Currently I've gotten as far as

```
SELECT
    DESCRIPTION,
    LEFT(DESCRIPTION, 
         CASE 
           WHEN CHARINDEX(',', DESCRIPTION) = 0 THEN LEN(DESCRIPTION) 
           ELSE charindex(',', DESCRIPTION) - 1 
         END) AS LEFTDESCRIPTION,
    RIGHT(DESCRIPTION, 
          CASE 
             WHEN CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(DESCRIPTION)) = 0 THEN '' 
             ELSE charindex(',', DESCRIPTION) - 1 
          END) AS RIGHTDESCRIPTION 
FROM TABLE
```

But the RIGHT portion doesn't seem to be correct, for example:

It gets a description of example,this and returns "ample,this" rather than just "this"

Comment: You're searching for the comma in the reversed description, but then indexing against the description without reversing it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you know how to get the contents `LEFT` of the comma, you can leverage the same manipulation logic on the `REVERSE`'d value to grab what would be to the `RIGHT` of the original string,

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(50) = 'example,this'
SELECT @Var
    , LEFT(@Var, CHARINDEX(',', @Var) - 1)                            -- returns 'example'
    , REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@Var), CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(@Var)) - 1)) -- returns 'this'
    -- or when using the RIGHT function,
    , RIGHT(@Var, LEN(@Var) - CHARINDEX(',', @Var))                   -- returns 'this'
```

Per Juan's comment, below is the same `SELECT` as above (this time selecting `RIGHT` route rather than the `REVERSE` logic) that would return the value when the comma delimiter is not found,

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(100) = 'example,this'
SELECT @Var
    , CASE WHEN @Var LIKE '%,%' THEN LEFT(@Var, CHARINDEX(',', @Var) - 1)
           ELSE @Var END
    , CASE WHEN @Var LIKE '%,%' THEN RIGHT(@Var, LEN(@Var) - CHARINDEX(',', @Var))
           ELSE @Var END
```

Comment: I think you should include validation for when `,` isnt there

Comment: That's a pretty smart solution, it worked perfect. I added in the validation Juan pointed out and it all worked.

Answer (score 1):

I would be inclined to use `stuff()` for this:

```
select description,
       left(description, charindex(',', description) - 1)  as leftdescription,
       stuff(description, 1, charindex(',', description), '')  as rightdescription
```

If you are concerned about `,` not being there, then use `case`:

```
select description,
       (case when description like '%,%'
             then left(description, charindex(',', description) - 1)
             else description
        end) as leftdescription,
       (case when description like '%,%'
             then stuff(description, 1, charindex(',', description), '')
        end) as rightdescription
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it. You were very close.

```
SELECT
    DESCRIPTION,
    LEFT(DESCRIPTION, 
         CASE 
           WHEN CHARINDEX(',', DESCRIPTION) = 0 THEN LEN(DESCRIPTION) 
           ELSE charindex(',', DESCRIPTION) - 1 
         END) AS LEFTDESCRIPTION,
    REVERSE(LEFT(Reverse(DESCRIPTION), 
          CASE 
             WHEN CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(DESCRIPTION)) = 0 THEN '' 
             ELSE charindex(',', REVERSE(DESCRIPTION)) - 1 
          END)) AS RIGHTDESCRIPTION 
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Var VARCHAR(50) = 'example,this'

SELECT LEFT(@Var, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @Var) - 1, -1), LEN(@Var))) LEFTDESCRIPTION,
       REPLACE(@Var, LEFT(@Var, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', @Var), 0), LEN(@Var))), '') RIGHTDESCRIPTION
```